# How to unzip a downloaded data and use a particular file from the unzipped file (index.html) to load in a UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, gzip, nsdata

I am stuck with unziping a zip file and fetch a paritcular file from that unzipped content (index.html) and finally use that index.html to load a UIWebview .

Am using GZIP library to unzip the file which am downloading

```
[data gunzippedData];
```

Is the method which am using to unzip the data using GZIP .

Answer (score 0):

For unzipping the file from web use the below code.

Dowbload ZipArchive.h and #import  in your file.

```
NSURL *urlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString: [tempDirOuter objectForKey:@"filename"]];
                             NSLog(@"txt File : %@",urlVersion);

                             NSError *error = nil;
                             // 2
                             NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlVersion options:0 error:&error];
                             NSString *textFilePath;
                             if(!error)
                             {
                                 // 3
                                 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                                 NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                                 NSString *strFileName = [tempDirOuter objectForKey:@"fileNameOnly"];
                                 NSString *zipPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];

                                 [data writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];

                                 ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
                                 // 1
                                 if ([za UnzipOpenFile: zipPath])
                                 {
                                     // 2
                                     BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo: path overWrite: YES];
                                     if (NO == ret){} [za UnzipCloseFile];

                                     // 3
                                     NSString *StrName = [strFileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".zip" withString:@".txt"];
                                     textFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:StrName];
                                 }
                                 if(!error)
                                 {
                                     // TODO: Unzip
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"Error saving file %@",error);
                                 }
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 NSLog(@"Error downloading zip file: %@", error);
                             }

                             NSString *webVersion = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

In string webVersion you will get the html path.

Comment: Thanks jadav i have some queries though : 
What type is tempDirOuter ?? What does it contain ??

Comment: Its my dictionary that comes from my webs service in which i got zip file url.